# Computing a line integral

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, stokes-theorem

Let $C$ be the curve which obtains from the intersection of the plane $z=x$ and the cylinder $x^{2}+y^{2}=1$, oriented counterclockwise. If $F$ is a vector field $F=(x,z,2y) \in \mathbb{R}^{3}$, compute
$$I= \oint_{C} F  \cdot dr $$

Hint: Use Stoke's Theorem.

I have that, $\nabla \times F= i$, then
$$I= \int_{S} (\nabla \times F) \cdot dS= \int \int_{D} 1dA $$
where $D= \{(x,y)| \quad x^{2} + y^{2} \le 1 \}$.

Is this fine?, I don't know if I am using correctly the theorem.

Comment: The theorem is fine, the problem is your surface. $x^2+y^2\leq 1$ is a surface that points upwards. With Stokes' theorem you have an infinite number of choices of surfaces to choose, so long as the they have the same boundary. What you need to do is draw out what you have and decide what surface to use.

Comment: Actually you may have gotten that right, but I'd like you to explain your though process better. Right now, you are claiming that $\hat{i}\cdot\hat{n} \cdot |J|dA = dA$, why is that true?

Comment: @NinadMunshi the surface are the points (x,y,z), so, if we parametrize, we obtain $S=\{ ( \cos (\theta), \sin(\theta), \cos(\theta)) | 0\le \theta \le pi \}$, and then whe have domain $D$

Comment: You cannot parametrize a surface using just one parameter $\theta$. If ccw means ccw when looking from the positive $z$ direcion, the direction of $d\boldsymbol S$ is not correct. If we choose a surface which is a graph $z = f(x, y)$, then $d\boldsymbol S = \nabla (z - f(x, y)) dx dy$. Which is why your result is correct (up to a sign).

Answer (score 1):

Let's call the surface enclosed by the curve $C$ as $D$.
Then, as you said, $$I= \oint_{C} F  \cdot dr = \int \int_{D} 1dA$$

One of the possible ways to parameterize the surface $D$ is:

$$\vec{\omega}(r,\theta) = <r\cos\theta,r\sin\theta, r\cos\theta >\quad 0 \leq r \leq 1, 0\leq \theta\leq 2\pi$$

Like you said, $\nabla \times F= <1,0,0>$ and now we need to get the normal vector of the surface (pointing upward) to evaluate the surface integral, which can be obtained by: $\vec{\omega_r}\times\vec{\omega_\theta}$ or $-\vec{\omega_r}\times\vec{\omega_\theta}$, choosing whichever having the positive $z$ value.

According to my calculation of the cross product, I get $\vec{\omega_r}\times\vec{\omega_\theta} = <-r, 0, r>$ .

Therefore the integral becomes $$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 <1,0,0>\cdot (\vec{\omega_r}\times\vec{\omega_\theta}) drd\theta$$

$$= \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 <1,0,0>\cdot  <-r, 0, r>drd\theta$$

$$= -\pi$$

Comment: If the surface is $\boldsymbol \omega(r, \theta)$, then $d\boldsymbol S = (\boldsymbol \omega_r \times \boldsymbol \omega_\theta) dr d\theta$, you have an extra $r$ factor.

Comment: That's true, because actually there was no $dxdy$ to begin with. Thanks for pointing that out!